# Kubernetes-Helm Charts pointing to a local docker image

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm playing around wiht minikube and I have a config in my `values.yaml` defined like this

```
image:
  repository: mydocker.jfrog.io/mysql
```

I want it to point a to a local docker image that lives locally `mysql/docker/dockerfile` I'm not sure what the syntax is can't find it in the docs

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check the list of images on your local machine with `docker image ls`. Let’s say `rajesh12/mysql` is the image you want to use:

```
image:
  repository: rajesh12/mysql
```

Comment: As I discovered, this doesn't work if you put `pullPolicy` to "Always". Solution: just stick to IfNotPresent pullPolicy and (re)build your image locally with --no-cache. Then delete the pod and you will automatically get a new pod with the new image.

Answer (score -4):

This is a late reply. But I solved it by this way...

```
image:
  registry: <docker_username>
  name: <docker_image_name>
```

Comment: where do you specify the password of the docker user name?