# How to install dependencies from requirements.txt in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, requirements.txt

I have a kubernetes cluster with Apache Airflow deployed. I used the [official helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) to deploy it. The DAG is stored in the git repository with which Apache Airflow is synchronized (using the dags.gitSync option).
Question: How can I get Apache Airflow to install the dependencies from the requirements.txt itself? This file is located at the following path:

```
dags
└── repo
    └── accounting
        ├── dag.py
        └── requirements
            └── requirements.txt
```

Apache Airflow version: 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used docker custom image.

```
FROM apache/airflow
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

and push docker repository(i use aws ecr).

edit helm deployment file(like values.yaml)

```
images:
  airflow:
    repository: {docker image repository uri}
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Can you specify  the dockerfile instead of the docker image reposittory uri?

Comment: could you check this url?
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839317/kubernetes-helm-charts-pointing-to-a-local-docker-image
in this reference, helm repository using already build docker image!

Comment: apache image workes, bitnami not

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Airflow image like Jongwho Park has mentioned, alternatively you can use [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#howto-operator-pythonvirtualenvoperator) and specify your pip packages in Operator.